# How to combine multiple rows in a relation into a tuple to perform calculations in PIG Latin

Tags: apache-pig

I have the following code:

```
pitcher_res = UNION pitcher_total_salary,pitcher_total_appearances;
dump pitcher_res;
```

The output is:

```
(8965000.0)
(22.0)
```

However, I want to calculate 8965000.0/22.0, so I need something like:

```
res = FOREACH some_relation GENERATE $0/$1;
```

Therefore I need to have some_relation = (8965000.0,22.0). How can I perform such a conversion?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `CROSS`.

> Computes the cross product of two or more relations.

https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#cross

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would have a unique identifier for each entry in your source relations. Then you can perform a join based on this identifier which results in the kind of relation you want to have.

Salary relation

```
salaries: pitcher_id, pitcher_total_salary
```

Total appearances relation

```
appearances: pitcher_id, pitcher_total_appearances
```

Join

```
pitcher_relation = join salaries by pitcher_id, appearances by pitcher_id;
```

Calculation

```
res = FOREACH pitcher_relation GENERATE pitcher_total_salary/pitcher_total_apperances;
```

Answer (score 0):

The below pig latin scripts will surely come to your rescue:

load the salary file

```
salary = load '/home/abhishek/Work/pigInput/pitcher_total_salary' as (salary:long);
```

load the appearances file

```
appearances = load '/home/abhishek/Work/pigInput/pitcher_total_appearances' as (appearances:long);
```

Now, use the CROSS command

```
C = cross salary, appearances
```

Then, the final output

```
res = foreach C generate salary/appearances;
```

Output

```
dump res
407500
```

Hope this helps